# How to pass cookie while returning a view from controller in Laravel 7.x?

Tags: php, web, laravel-7

In laravel 7.x is there any way to pass the cookie to the client while returning view?

Similar to like:

```
return view("welcome")->cookie('name','value',$min);
```

Answer (score 10):

Well, I did some research and found that, there are some ways. The two I am familiar about is via "queue" and other is by using 'response'.

Via response:

```
return response(view('welcome'))->cookie('name','value',$min);
```

Via Queue:

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('name','value',$min));
return view('welcome');
```

The Queue approach is more elegant and clean, but you need to understand that, Laravel pushes the cookie into queue. And when the final response is sent back to the client, it will automatically attach that queued cookie to the response.